# How to find occupied space on a floppy disk in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, dos

I have a homework assignment to make a simple program in assembly language for the 8086 family of processors that reads and prints the total occupied space on a floppy.

Now I have several problems. I know I have to use interrupts but I have no idea which one and how it works, I tried Norton Guide but I didn't find what I was looking for. Another problem is that I do not own a floppy or have a machine that has a floppy ... well I have absolutely no way to test this program.

In other words I'm stuck

EDIT:

Also how do I multiply 3 Words ? Ax * Cx * Dx ? because Word * Word = Double Word ... and I have no idea how to multiply Double Word with Word.

Comment: Where in the world are you going to school that this is a *homework* assignment? I hope you're taking a course entitled "Vintage Computing".

Comment: The idea behind this course is to help us understand how the processor works. I personally get it because now I understand a whole lot of quirks in c++. Things that I thought were stupid and limitations that I thought were annoying. You could argue that this is useless ... most of my colleagues do in fact, but there are reasons to believe this could possibly help. I am somewhere in-between. BUT this particular homework is useless, annoying, time-wasting and just ... ancient.

Comment: Kalec, the way to compute the amount of occupied space on a floppy varies tremendously from operating system to operating system, so please correct me if I am wrong, but I added the 'dos' tag, because I assume that is what you meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a little vague on this, but it sounds like you're coding against the MS-DOS INT21 API.

If that's the case, you're looking for two commands:

- [1Ch (Get Allocation Information for Specific Drive)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2591.htm) -- if you multiply together AL, CX and DX, you'll get the size of the disk in bytes.
- [36h (Get Free Disk Space)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2751.htm).

The difference between the total size and the free space will give the occupied space.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the question is a bit vague but I know little about assembly and even less about floppies. However this is indeed what I am looking for, thank you. Now however my question is this: How can I verify if my code is working without a floppy ?

Comment: @Kalec: IIRC, in MS-DOS one could use the `ASSIGN` and `SUBST` commands to substitute one drive letter for another; perhaps this might come in handy. Also, take a look at http://www.freewarereview.info/2006-03/virtual_floppy_drive_-_floppy_disk_imaging_and_virtualization_part_ii.html